# File access speed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, theory

I have got a theoretical question:
I think to use files that store an object's position.(each line contains coordinates x and  y)
The data is going to be read from the file 3 times per second.

Is the delay 0.3 s of reading a coordinates from the file is too small? Will my program get necessary information in time?

Thanks.

Comment: reading from file ( read from the question above ) / writing to file  (read from the comment below )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

540 objects in array is not too much, if it is just texts / numbers. Just do the read-write job in memory. You can write the array to file after the 3-minute.

Comment: Will it affect on stability or anything else?

Comment: Not likely - like Shivan said, you're far safer storing in memory and writing it to file at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I'd imagine that you could easily read this amount of data from a file at 3 times per second - but this seems like an odd design approach?  Perhaps you can expand on what you're trying to achieve for some different ideas?

Comment: I want to record an object's position 3 times per second for a 3 minutes. Arrays are convenient but I suppose that about 540 objects in an array is too much, so I think to write necessary data to file instead.

Comment: Nah, like above - 540 objects isn't too much for an array.  Depending on the complexity of the content however, you may want to choose a C style array for better speed of access.